# Refresh (reload) a page once using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, refresh, reload

I'm wondering how to refresh/reload a page (or even specific div) once(!) using jQuery?

Ideally in a way right after the `DOM structure` is available (cf. `onload` event) and not negatively affecting `back button` or `bookmark` functionality.

Please, note: `replace()`  is not allowed due to third-party restrictions.

Comment: I am missing something in your question. What do you mean by "refresh" the page. If the page has loaded, reloading immediately would just load the exact same content, right? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm working on a template which comes up "normally" first but is forced into an iFrame when refreshed/reloaded. Now I want the page to display in that iFrame on its first "call" as well. TIA!

Comment: I think you should read this article http://mycodingtricks.com/snippets/javascript/refresh-page-using-jquery/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Alright, I think I got what you're asking for. Try this

```
if(window.top==window) {
    // You're not in a frame, so you reload the site.
    window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 3000); //Reloads after three seconds
}
else {
    //You're inside a frame, so you stop reloading.
}
```

---

If it is once, then just do

```
$('#div-id').triggerevent(function(){
    $('#div-id').html(newContent);
});
```

If it is periodically

```
function updateDiv(){
    //Get new content through Ajax
    ...
    $('#div-id').html(newContent);
}

setInterval(updateDiv, 5000); // That's five seconds
```

So, every five seconds the div #div-id content will refresh. Better than refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Thanks but I want the page to refresh/reload only ONCE (per browser session if possible)...?

Comment: What's the trigger for reloading? a certain event or just time?

Comment: trigger: the first "call" of the page (sorry, my english is kinda poor *g*)

Comment: omfgroflmao, you're a genius! The "edited" version is exactly what I was looking for (the whole day btw...). Is it possible to add an optional time trigger here? So that location.reload is executed - let's say - after 3 seconds...? TIA (YOU've really made my day!)

Comment: Yeah, sure, just change location.reload() with window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 3000);

Comment: Great! So, this is how it should work with the time trigger (for IE7 only), right?

<!--[if IE 7]>
<script language="JavaScript">
if(window.top==window) {
    window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 3000);
} else {
}
</script>
<![endif]-->

BTW: Any chance to realize this with scripting turned off (as a backup)?

Comment: Yes and no, you need JS to do this.

Comment: OK, then I'll advise my customers via <noscript> notice to turn on JS. Thanks again! You, this site - really awesome! Bye.

Answer (score 67):

To reload, you can try this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: can you explain the bool argument?

Comment: The argument to the location.reload function determines
if the browser should retrieve the document from the
web-server. 

If needed to pull the document from the web-server again (such as where the document contents change dynamically) pass the argument as 'true'

http://grizzlyweb.com/webmaster/javascripts/refresh.asp

Answer (score 40):

```
window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

Comment: bad rep this, jQuery asked HTML given. -1

Comment: This will not work if URL have hash like: http://mycodingtricks.com/#cool

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Check if the current URL contains '#'
            if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1)
            {
                // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
                url = document.URL+"#";
                location = "#";

                //Reload the page
                 location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Due to the `if` condition, the page will reload only once.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#div-id').click(function(){

   location.reload();
        });
```

This is the correct syntax.

```
$('#div-id').html(newContent); //This doesnt work
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a jQuery refresh function, because this is JavaScript basics.

Try this:

```
<body onload="if (location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) location.replace(location.href+'?reload');">
```

Comment: Nice one. you can even put it inside a function:  <body onload="javascript:init()"> and function init(){ if (location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) location.replace(location.href+'&reload');}

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reload (Refresh) Page Using Jquery</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#reload').click(function() {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="reload" >Reload (Refresh) Page Using</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your file and the site will refresh every 30 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = Refresh;

    function Refresh() {
        setTimeout("refreshPage();", 30000);
    }
    function refreshPage() {
        window.location = location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Another one is: Add in the head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 - location = location
 - location = location.href
 - location = window.location
 - location = self.location
 - location = window.location.href
 - location = self.location.href
 - location = location['href']
 - location = window['location']
 - location = window['location'].href
 - location = window['location']['href']
```

You don't need jQuery for this. You can do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', $('#iframe').attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}

<a href="javascript:timedRefresh(2000)">image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing page with javascript, you can simply use:

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="history.go(0)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `this` reference along with `location.reload()`
check this, it will work.

```
this.location.reload();
```